# jScrollPane cropping vertical content Chrome / Webkit

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, webkit, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm trying to implement jScrollPane - v2.0.0beta11 on a project similar to what they have done on www.rolex.com, however I have an issue of the copy being vertically cropped within Chrome/webkit?

See here (need to click 'VIEW HTML' at the bottom to see the correct page)

http://www.rolex.com/en/rolex-watches/day-date/parachrom

I'm getting the exact same issue with the most recent 2.00 beta1, tested on all OS and only happens in webkit browsers. It seems on init the scrollBars are applied correctly but upon focus and scrolling it reduces the scrollable height? so you can't access the bottom few pixels or the top upon scrolling back up.

You can fix it by focusing on another element, I noticed if you scroll the box to cause the issue, then focus on another element (like the arrows) or outside the browser, it fixes it. Could be an issue with the initFocusHandlers?

Noticed a few people having this issue, but seemed to have fixed it with script call ordering or reInitialiseOnImageLoad / autoReinitialise - none worked for me

Driving me pretty insane as have spent a few days trying to fix it, any advice would be wicked.

Cheers